# How to redirect users to specific screen of App from URI scheme in React navigation?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, deep-linking

Currently below URI scheme redirects the user to the home page in Android:

```
wagal://reset/password?token=123456789
```

And this is how I configured it in `HomeStack.js`

```
const config = {
  screens: {
    ResetPassword: "reset"
  },
};

const linking = {
  prefixes: ["wagal://"],
  config
};

function homeStack() {

  return (
    <NavigationContainer linking={linking} fallback={<Text>Loading...</Text>}>
      <Stack.Navigator>

        <Stack.Screen component={ResetPassword} name="ResetPassword" />

        // ...

      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

`HomeStack` is referenced in `App.js`:

```
<Provider store={store}>
  <HomeStack />
</Provider>
```

As you can see I am trying to redirect this URI scheme to `ResetPassword` screen, but due to some reasons it is always redirected to HomeScreen.

What is the reason it isn't working? I followed [documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/configuring-links/#marking-params-as-optional) and I couldn't find any reasons why it isn't working?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: As a fast solution: try to clean the project and run again: cd android && ./gradlew clean && cd .. && npx react-native run-android

Comment: Did you prepare your app's `AndroidManifest.xml`, too, as described here? https://reactnavigation.org/docs/deep-linking#android

Comment: Yes, `AndroidManifest.xml` is configured. That's why URI scheme redirects the web page to App.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution, so that deep linking knows exactly where and with which params in your application to redirect

```
const config = {
  screens: {
    ResetPassword: "reset/password/:token"
  },
};
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. 

This is still redirecting to home page. I also cleaned build files. It doesn't work.

Comment: same issue. try from last fiver days. but no solution for this.